# Remove all GMSMarker from GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, marker, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I placed 100 GMSMarkers on GMSMapView. How to remove all the GMSMarkers?

In Google Sdk Version 1.6 for iOS.

Marker array(in GMSMapView (Overlays) file) which will be holding the GMSMarkers list is deprecated. By using this i was removing all GMSMarker from GMSMapView.

Is there any other way to remove all GMSMarker from GMSMapView in iOS?

Answer (score 43):

Use `[mapView clear]` to achieve required functionality. :-)

Update:

**Swift:**

```
mapView.clear()
```

Answer (score 10):

They deprecated those methods but you can use `[mapView clear]` to remove all overlays from the map. This includes all markers, polylines and groundOverlays.

Hope it helps!

Comment: what if you just want to remove the markers and not the polylines and groundOverlays. is there a way to get a list of added markers?

Answer (score 5):

Add all markers into NSMutableArray, as you add them to the map. Then when you need to remove them, iterate through the array and set each marker's .map property to nil.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.x**

If someone is looking to clear only a particular `marker` then you can use this:

`marker.map = nil`

If you want to remove everything from the map, like `polyline`, `marker` etc. then you can use

`self.mapView.clear()`.

It will clear everything from the map.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.x**

```
self.mapView.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.....

```
[self.MapView clear];
```